# Retrieving german text from mysql database

Tags: mysql

Im having a problem retrieving german text from the database.
Im using mysql 5.0.8
the table contains zipcodes and city names in austria
table properties: charset-utf8, collation - utf8_general_ci, engine - innodb

i retrieve the entries through php.
here's the content type is used :

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

upon retreiving, it shows special characters example : Wien-V�h

am i using the wrong charset for the table?

Comment: With what scripting language are you processing the mysql results? PHP/ASP/Ruby? Those languages usually have functions to encode your db connection using UTF8 aswell.

Comment: im using php (php framework - kohana 2.3.4)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

just after establishing connection to mysql.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and this one
`SET CHARACTER SET utf8;`
but i still get garbage characters upon retrieving

Comment: Are you sure that inside database you have utf8 data? Could you try and make some test script using PDO and `set names utf8;` and select some rows and chaeck if they are really utf8?